# Processing errors in Retrofit Android REST client

Tags: android, retrofit

We are using the Square client Retrofit in our Android app. In some cases, we created custom deserializers where we raise `Exceptions` which want to catch in one unique place: the `setErrorHandler` function provided by the library. After processing the exception, we want to stop it here, avoiding this throwable to be returned by the function, but we are not able to do it.

For instance, the authentication system of the API we are working with returns 5** errors when the user needs to reset his auth token. We want to process this in one single point, not in every API call around our code.

Any idea to make Retrofit forget about this exception?